# unity- select 2D game object in mobile touch

Tags: unity-game-engine

i want to know what is best way to select 2D object in unity mobile
for example i want to select one object and a menu show up for upgrade

i already searched but didnt find something good
if you write both code and  good references would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a Button component to that object and add an OnClick() function call to it :

[See a sample in Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html)

or you can use Touches to have control over different phases :

[See a sample in Unity Tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/2d-roguelike-tutorial/adding-mobile-controls)

Comment: i added button component to  my 2d object,  used onclick() function.but still cant click on object ( i did same things that i do with normal buttons,it works on normal buttons).     something missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can add button instead of your GameObject and choose button sprite like as your GameObject's sprite then you will writing function to button to show your menu